# the trait bound `mock::Test: pallet_rmrk_core::Config` is not satisfied

Tags: pallet, mock, rmrk

I'm writing a pallet, which depends on `pallet-rmrk-core`, based on `pallet-template`.

In `lib.rs` I wrote:

```
#[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_rmrk_core::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }
```

Now the `mock.rs` from pallet-template errors:

```
impl pallet_cases::Config for Test {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    type Event = Event;
}
```

```
the trait bound `mock::Test: pallet_rmrk_core::Config` is not satisfied
the trait `pallet_rmrk_core::Config` is not implemented for `mock::Test`rustcE0277
lib.rs(33, 46): required by a bound in `pallet::Config`
```

My full mock.rs looks like this:

```
use crate as pallet_cases;
use frame_support::traits::{ConstU16, ConstU64};
use frame_system as system;
use sp_core::H256;
use sp_runtime::{
    testing::Header,
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, IdentityLookup},
};

type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system,
        PalletCases: pallet_cases,
    }
);

impl system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = ConstU64<250>;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = ();
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = ConstU16<42>;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_cases::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
}

// Build genesis storage according to the mock runtime.
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    system::GenesisConfig::default()
        .build_storage::<Test>()
        .unwrap()
        .into()
}
```

I already tried to add pallet_rmrk_core to the runtime and did a `impl pallet_rmrk_core::Config for Test` but it ended in just much more errors.

What do I miss?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already tried to add pallet_rmrk_core to the runtime and did a impl pallet_rmrk_core::Config for Test but it ended in just much more errors.

This is the correct solution. You have specified in your trait that the `rmrk_core::Config` is a super trait. This means when implementing your `Config` trait the type also needs to implement the `rmrk_core::Config` trait. Whatever the errors are that you are getting in this case, you will also need to fix them.